# Infinite dimensional analysis

Tags: measure-theory, metric-spaces, transformation, ergodic-theory

[image]

I got completely confused with this theorem .

How could this measure be invariant for this kind of transformation?

I would be very grateful if someone could explain it

Comment: May I know what book is this?

Comment: @user284331 infinite dimensional analysis https://books.google.com/books/about/Infinite_Dimensional_Analysis.html?id=6jjY2Vi3aDEC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume 1) holds, then $\mu=\mu\circ\xi^{-1}$, then $\mu\circ T_{\xi}(f)=\mu(T_{\xi}(f))=\mu(f\circ\xi)=\left<f,\mu\circ\xi^{-1}\right>=\left<f,\mu\right>=\mu(f)$, so $\mu=\mu\circ T_{\xi}$, this is the invariant.

Comment: I meant what does m is T-invariant mean ?

Comment: $\mu=\mu\circ T_{\xi}$, this one ($T_{\xi}$-invariant).

Comment: m is measure on hotel sets how can I composite it with T ?

Comment: Actually one used to identify the measure with the linear functional $f\rightarrow\displaystyle\int fdm$.

Comment: So with the linear functional $L_{m}$ associated with the measure $m$, one has $m(A)=L_{m}(\chi_{A})$ and actually you can prove that such a correspondence is unique, so we identify the measure $m$ with the canonical linear functional $L_{m}$. Now the $T_{\xi}$-invariant becomes the matter of asking if $L_{m}\circ T_{\xi}=L_{m}$. An abuse of notation one writes if $\mu=\mu\circ T_{\xi}$.